# VueJS: Recommended way to cache component data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

In my VueJS application I have multiple pages (views, components) which load individual data from some WebApi. The response data should be cached in the VueJS application until the user explicitly hits the "clear cache" button.

Storing the response data in the "data" member of each component does not work as the components get recreated when navigating through the pages using vue-router.

I am aware of vuex to store an application state but that seems to be rather an application central storage than a component local one. I saw that vuex store can be modularized but still the state of one component could be accessed by a different component.

What is the recommended way of storing (private?) data/state in a VueJS component such that it survives page navigation?

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." There's no recommended way, it's solved per case. Something like vue-query fits it. Vuex is not the worst way. *still the state of one component could be accessed by a different component* - you could teach your components discipline, I guess.

Comment: True ;-) thx for sharing your thoughts ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use vuex store so as to share data between components. Dispatch store actions to mutate your modules state and get your data everywhere in your components. If data has not be shared in the app, use component's state.

Comment: i dont want to share the data across components but rather keep it private BUT i also want to preserve it when switching between the components (there are different components on different pages and i navigate between with vue-router). As to my observation components are recreated during navigation so how could i preserve the state?

Comment: Could you use session data and then preserve some of it to fetch it from an API upon switching from component to component? Storing anything on a local machine will not be private therefore you are left with your backend.

Comment: I do cache many things in the backend but i was wondering how i could even avoid frontend backend roundtrip when just switching pages without actually requesting anything from backend